# Output unix time in alias

Tags: bash, time, alias

I'm running an online store where I can put a variable versiontag to includes JS and CSS as a cachebuster. I. e.

```
styles.css?v2018_01
```

Wherein the `2018_01` is the version tag. Now I also have a CLI tool that makes it quick to set like so

```
mr config:set 'design/head/meta_version_tag' [insert_my_var_here]
```

And what I want to do is create a Bash alias that sets the variable to the Unix timestamp whenever it is run. I know I can get the Unix timestamp with `date +%s`.

So I would make an alias like this:

```
mr config:set 'design/head/meta_version_tag' date +%s
```

But the CLI interprets the `date +%s` as a string, rather than getting its output first.

So what I need is an output like this:

```
mr config:set 'design/head/meta_version_tag' 1519747390
```

And so my question is; how can I get the output of the unix datestamp in my alias?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided you use `bash` you can use [Command Substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst):

```bsh
mr config:set 'design/head/meta_version_tag' $(date +%s)
```

This will first run `date +%s` in a subshell and include the output as a string, see `man bash` under EXPANSION/Command Substitution:

> Bash performs the expansion by  executing  `command`  and  replacing 
>   the
>          command  substitution with the standard output of the command, with any
>          trailing newlines deleted.

There's no need to quote the command substitution (like you would normally do) in this case, as the output of `date +%s` doesn't have any whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
mr config:set 'design/head/meta_version_tag' $(date +%s)
```

Or,

```
alias dothething='mr config:set "design/head/meta_version_tag" $(date +%s)'
```